# How can I send only a list of few selected items to another activity using intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

The app is a Food Ordering App. I have added only few dishes from many in an array using intent.After I click proceed to cart button how can i see my dishes in another activity that are only added.

This is the code where i take the added dishes in array.

```
 val desc = dishList[position]
        holder.txtDishName.text = desc.desName
        holder.txtCost_for_one.text = desc.desCost_for_one
        holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            if (holder.btnAdd.text == "ADD") {
                val obj = Cart(
                    desc.id,
                    desc.desName,
                    desc.desCost_for_one,
                    desc.restaurant_id
                )
                addToCart.add(obj)
                holder.btnAdd.text = "Remove"
                val favColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, R.color.colorPrimary)
                holder.btnAdd.setBackgroundColor(favColor)

            } else{
               for (i in 0 until addToCart.size ){
                   if (addToCart[i].cId == desc.id){
                       addToCart.removeAt(i)
                   }
               }
                holder.btnAdd.text = "Add"
                val favColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, R.color.colorAccent)
                holder.btnAdd.setBackgroundColor(favColor)
            }
            val intent = Intent(context, DescriptionActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("addToCart",addToCart)
            

        }
        
    }
```

This is the code where i click on the proceed to cart button.

```
btnProceed.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CartActivity::class.java)
            //intent.getStringArrayExtra("addToCart")
            intent.getStringExtra("addToCart")
            startActivity(intent)
```

But after running the app the CartActivity comes Empty.

Comment: putParcebleArrayList?

Comment: Have a look at my answer and get back to me with your problem status.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use a string I think you should convert your list to json.

For example use Gson

```
var gson = Gson()
val myObject = myObject(...)
val jsonString = gson.toJson(myObject)
intent.putExtra("myObjectKey", jsonString)
```

And after that you can get string like

```
val jsonString = intent.getStringExtra("myObjectKey")
var myObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, myObject::class.java)
```

For using Gson

`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'`